# How do I enumerate all string properties in an interface?

Tags: delphi, interface, delphi-xe7

I want (if possible) to enumerate all string properties in an interface that looks like this:

```
IXMLDocumentSummaryType = interface(IXMLNode)
    ['{AD394EAD-1253-4CA5-9F0A-76122CB53D88}']
    { Property Accessors }
    function Get_Uid: UnicodeString;
    function Get_RsUid: UnicodeString;
    //etc

    { Methods & Properties }
    property Uid    : UnicodeString read Get_Uid write Set_Uid;
    property RsUid  : UnicodeString read Get_RsUid write Set_RsUid;
    property Meta   : UnicodeString read Get_Meta write Set_Meta;
    property Error  : UnicodeString read Get_Error write Set_Error;
  end;
```

There are lots of text properties and I am interested in only 43. So, I have the name of those 43 in a static array.

```
   Fields: array[0..42] of RSummary= (
        (Name: 'RsUid' ; Value: ''),
        (Name: 'GbUid' ; Value: ''),
        etc...
    );
```

Now I would like to enumerate the properties and automatically put the values of those properties in the array.
I have Delphi XE7.

I have tried this:

```
var
  C: TRttiContext;
  T: TRttiType;
  F: TRttiField;
  P: TRttiProperty;
begin
  T:= C.GetType(IXMLDocumentSummaryType)   <----- not working
```

Comment: What Delphi version? Recent versions have different RTTI capabilities than older ones, so the version matters.

Comment: Delphi XE 7 (but IF possible Delphi XE would be of interest also).

Comment: You can't get information about interfaces like that through RTTI. You need an instance of the class that implements the interface.

Comment: @Ken And that assumes that you've put the same properties from the interface into the object - properties may or may not exist on either side.

Comment: @Jerry: Well, I thought that went without saying. You clearly can't get properties from the class instance that aren't there, with or without RTTI.

Comment: @Ken It's quite common to define the properties only the interface which is what Jerry is getting at. Furthermore, there's no reason to expect that, given an interface, you can obtain an implementing object. Doing so is quite a dubious practise anyway.

Comment: @David: I said nothing about using RTTI to obtain an implementing object, AFAICT. I said that to get those properties via RTTI you need an instance of the class that  implements it. I'd presume that if you have access to a variable that you're trying to obtain RTTI from, you'd have that variable already. Thanks for interpreting what Jerry intended to say, though.

Comment: @Ken I said nothing about RTTI to obtain an implementing object. Given that the premise of the question is that we start with an interface, let's do that. In other words, it is reasonable to assume that there is no implementing object to hand.

Comment: @David: *Furthermore, there's no reason to expect that, given an interface, you can obtain an implementing object. Doing so is quite a dubious practise anyway.* Sorry. I must have forgotten my reading glasses today; I could swear that's *exactly* what those words say.

Comment: @Ken I don't understand your point.

Comment: "it is reasonable to assume that there is no implementing object to hand" - Yes. I don't have an implementing object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces properties are very different from class properties. An interface only has methods and the properties are just sugar.

You won't get RTTI for interface properties because there is no such RTTI.

Comment: This sucks. Fortunately, I already have the manual assignment for the 43 'properties' of interest. So, it seems I will stick with that. My hope was that I could make the code look less spaghetti.

Comment: You can enumerate the functions that have no parameters and return a string and whose names begins with 'Get' which would almost certainly be what you need.

Comment: It's the Java way.  It's a way of thinking certainly, but "interesting" isn't how I would describe it.  :)  In all seriousness, this is a good suggestion, I'm just having a little dig here at the lack of formal property syntax in Java.  In fact, RemObjects applied exactly this way of thinking with their Pascal/C# compilers for Java (not just for strings).  When working with Java classes, functions following this getXXX/setXXX pattern are surfaced as properties (i.e. without the get/set and allowing assignment to "call" the set method), the compiler generates calls to the corresponding get/set.